# Dynamic (time-indexed) Maximum Flow - Ford-Fulkerson

Tags: algorithm, time, ford-fulkerson

How could you modify the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to account for a time constraint? For example, if you were given a maximum amount of time and each edge takes 1 unit of time, how could you find the maximum flow?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to encode `T` time steps in graph problems is to make `T+1` copies of the graph's vertices, then for each arc from `u` to `v`, make `T` of them, from `u` in copy `i` to `v` in copy `i+1` for `i` from `0` to `T-1`.